# Changing first letter of a filename to uppercase

Tags: command-line, filename

How can one change the first letter of a filename to uppercase using a command line?
IS there any command line to do so?

Answer (score 25):

Using the `rename` command:

```
rename -n 's/./\U$&/' *
```

- `-n` only shows what changes will be made. After you verify the changes, run without `-n` to actually rename the files.
- `s/./\U$&/`: `s`ubstitutes the first character (`.`) with the uppercase (`\U`) of whatever was matched (`$&`).

Example:

```
$ ls
bar  foo
$ rename -n 's/./\U$&/' *
rename(bar, Bar)
rename(foo, Foo)
```